# Calling mongoimport from a script

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to run a script from windows powershell:

```
 .\mongo.exe  localhost:27017/test --quiet test.js
```

that calls mongoimport:

```
var c_env = 'dev';

 if (c_env === "dev") 
 { 
 ./mongoimport.exe -d noeldb -c order_notifications --file "D:\Utilities\mongodb\bin\mycollection.json";
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Tue May 29 09:47:00 SyntaxError: syntax error D:\Noel\Temp\test.js:5
failed to load: D:\Noel\Temp\test.js
```

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: see http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Scripting+the+shell

Comment: Not sure If you can execute external functions/apps from inside Javascript, but you could structure your code differently avoiding this problem.

Why do you need to check if it's dev environment from inside javascript? Let's check your conditions from the shell script and take appropriate actions there. So you can avoid to execute Javascript code from mongo.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When you run a JS script file the commands inside of it will be executed from the mongo shell.

You are doing the equivalent of:

```
C:\> mongo.exe
MongoDB shell
connecting to test
> ./mongoimport.exe ...
```

This will not work because mongo shell is expecting mongo syntax (Javascript) not Windows/powershell commands.

If you want to invoke mongoimport.exe from a script the simplest way would be to do it from a DOS/powershell script.